# Date format from Android (java) to Spring Boot

Tags: java, android, spring, date, datetime

I'm working with Android Studio (java) to make the front part of my application, and I work with Spring Boot to the back part.

The SQL database uses TimeStamp.

So my problem is that when I send an object from front (Android) to back (Spring) throws an error:

> Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.Date` from String "Feb 18, 2021 2:47:40 AM": not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value 'Feb 18, 2021 2:47:40 AM': Cannot parse date "Feb 18, 2021 2:47:40 AM": not compatible with any of standard forms ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", "yyyy-MM-dd")); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.Date` from String "Feb 18, 2021 2:47:40 AM": not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value 'Feb 18, 2021 2:47:40 AM': Cannot parse date "Feb 18, 2021 2:47:40 AM": not compatible with any of standard forms ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
> at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 123] (through reference chain: com.prueba.dataproviders.model.Solicitud["fecha"])]

So I guess the problem its from Android sending information to Spring, but I don't know how to handle it...

MORE INFORMATION:
This is an example when I send information from Spring to Android:

```
{
    "id": 23,
    "fecha": "2021-02-18T02:47:40.000+00:00",
    "estadoSolicitud": 1
}
```

I keep the attribute "fecha" which its a date in a Date variable.
But when I send the same object to back it sends:

```
{"estadoSolicitud":0,"fecha":"Feb 18, 2021 2:47:40 AM","id":23}
```

Thank you in advance <3

**CODE:**
**At *Spring* Solicitud class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "solicitud")
public class Solicitud implements Serializable{

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
   @Column(name = "id")
   private int id;

   @Column(name = "fecha", insertable = false)
   private Date fecha;

   @Column(name="estadoSolicitud")
   private int estadoSolicitud; // "0 Pendiente, 1 Realizada 2 Rechazada
```

**At *Spring* the the post method that receives the `<Solicitud>` object:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/solicitudes/gestionarSolicitud/{estadoSol}", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<Object> setSolicitud(@RequestBody Solicitud solicitud, @PathVariable(value="estadoSol") int estadoSol ){
        
    Optional<Solicitud> optionalSolicitud = solicitudService.gestionarSolicitud(solicitud, estadoSol);
    if (optionalSolicitud.isPresent()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Object>(optionalSolicitud.get(), HttpStatus.OK);}

    } else {
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(null , HttpStatus.OK);
    }   
}
```

**At *Android* (front part) Solicitud Model:**

```
public class Solicitud  implements Serializable {

private int id;
private Date fecha;
private int estadoSolicitud; // 0 pendiente 1 Aceptada 2 Rechazada
//getters && setters...
```

}

**At *Android* the request method that's request the post method to back:**

```
public interface SolicitudService {

@POST("/solicitudes/gestionarSolicitud/{estadoSol}")
Call<Solicitud> gestionarSolitud( @Body Solicitud solicitud,     @Path("estadoSol") int estadoSol);
}
```

***At Android* the function that uses the request method:**

```
        private void gestionarSolicitud(@NotNull Solicitud solicitud, int estadoSol) {
        SolicitudService solicitudService = ApiClient.getClient().create(SolicitudService.class);
        Call<Solicitud> call = solicitudService.gestionarSolitud(solicitud, estadoSol);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<Solicitud>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Solicitud> call, Response<Solicitud> response) {
                Solicitud solActualizada = response.body();

                if (solActualizada != null && solActualizada.getEstadoSol() == estadoSol) {
                    if (estadoSol == 1)
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Usuario registrado correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    else if (estadoSol == 2)
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Solicitud rechazada", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Ups! Ha ocurrido un error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Solicitud> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Ups! Ha ocurrido un error del servidor.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });


    }
```

Comment: I didn't fully understand your question. But in general good way to handle these is send a fixed/parsable date string from client and use DateFormatter to parse it back on server.  Jackson (the default json library in Spring Boot) comes with variable annotation to define the date format at field level.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-dates#jsonformat see this

Comment: Use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format to send the date and time both ways, like `2021-02-18T02:47:40.000+00:00`.

Comment: [A Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), please?

Comment: I uploaded the information with the code i use... the problem its when i send the "Solicitud" object to Spring at the method "gestionarSolicitud"...

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to try [**Joda Time library**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/userguide.html) as a common middleware for your date fields.

Comment: *Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to `java.time` (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.* (Joda-Time home page) On the Android side you may use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) to have the java.time functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown any actual code, so a definitive answer isn't possible, but you need to make sure that whatever you are using to serialize your java objects to Json on the Android side properly serializes Dates to ISO-8601 format.

Most mainstream Json serializers, e.g. Gson, will do that by default.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is saying that the value you are sending from client side(android) is having different data type, what you are fetching in back-end (Spring).

At both end the datatype must be same.

Please try this

Spring Code : You can mention the date format with JsonFormat annotation

String DATE_FORMAT_MM_DD_YYYY = "MM/dd/yyyy"

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = DATE_FORMAT_MM_DD_YYYY)
private Date fetching_date;
```

For Android Code : Get the date and you can change the date formats using below code
You can define the date formats like this :

```
const val DATE_FORMAT_yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss_a = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a"
const val DATE_FORMAT_MMM_dd_yyyy = "MMM dd, yyyy"
const val DATE_FORMAT_MMM_dd_yyyy_HH_MM_AA = "MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm aa"
const val DATE_FORMAT_YYYY_MM_DD = "yyyy-MM-dd"

//Convertion of one date format to another
        fun convertDateFormat(oldFormat: String, newFormat: String, dateString: String): String {
            var sdf = SimpleDateFormat(oldFormat)
            try {
                val date = sdf.parse(dateString)
                sdf = SimpleDateFormat(newFormat, getLocalForDateFormat())
                return sdf.format(date)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            return ""
        }
```

Send the date from android to back-end in request.

Comment: You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Android 26  and later has *java.time* built-in, while modern tooling makes most of the functionality available in earlier Android via "API desugaring".